# URLSearchParam type {property: value} is not assignable to undefined & Argument Type {property: value} not assignable to {property: value}

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, request, typescript2.0

I keep getting this error when I try to execute the following code. Basically it takes in the given refresh token and send a POST request with the URLSearchParams to the URL. But for some reason URLSearch params keeps on throwing an error.

[image]

#### Code

```js
const getAccessToken = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${basic}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token,
    }),
  })
  return response.json()
}
```

where `refresh_token` is a constant defined by an enviornment variable.

#### Error

```
Argument of type '{ grant_type: string; refresh_token: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[][] | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | undefined'.
  Type '{ grant_type: string; refresh_token: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `refresh_token` is potentially `undefined` and `URLSearchParams` only supports fields with string values.

There are several options here...

1. Provide a fallback string value

   ```js
   new URLSearchParams({
     grant_type: "refresh_token",
     refresh_token: refresh_token ?? ""
   })
   ```
2. Add parameters optionally

   ```js
   const body = new URLSearchParams({ grant_type: "refresh_token" });
   if (refresh_token) {
     body.append("refresh_token", refresh_token);
   }
   ```
3. If you're sure that `refresh_token` is not `undefined`, assert it as so

   ```js
   new URLSearchParams({
     grant_type: "refresh_token",
     refresh_token: refresh_token!
   })
   ```

Comment: I totally didn't realize. Looking back at my code I forgot to add a check for undefined value for the refresh_token. Thank you for this, I really do appreciate you explaining the issue, as well as providing solutions! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

To solve this all I did was remove the URLSearchParams function completley and just write the search parameters manually. If anyone else knows how to fix this issue while still using URLSearchParams please let me know.

###### Before

```js
body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token,
      })
```

###### After

```js
body: `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${refresh_token}`
```

##### Final Code

```js
const getAccessToken = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${basic}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${refresh_token}`
  })
  return response.json()
}
```